# TSQL - Split delimited String into columns

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, ssis, ssis-2008

---

### The Problem

I have a number of filename strings that I want to parse into columns using a tilda as delimiter. The strings take on the static format:

- **Filepath** example `C:\My Documents\PDF`
- **Surname** example `Walker`
- **First Name** example `Thomas`
- **Birth Date** example `19991226`
- **Document Created Datetime** example `20180416150322`
- **Document Extension** example `.pdf`

So a full concatenated example would be something like:

```
C:\My Documents\PDF\Walker~Thomas~19991226~20180416150322.pdf
```

I want to ignore the file path and extension given in the string and only parse the following values into columns:

- Surname, First Name, Birth Date, Document Created Datetime

So something like:

```
SELECT Surname = --delimitedString[0]
       FirstName = --delimitedString[1]
       --etc.
```

---

### What I have tried

I know that I have several tasks I would need to perform in order to split the string, first I would need to trim off the extension and file path so that I can return a string delimited by tildas (~).

This is problem one for me, however problem 2 is splitting the new delimted string itself i.e.

```
Walker~Thomas~19991226~20180416150322
```

Ive had a good read through this very comprehensive [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2647/how-do-i-split-a-string-so-i-can-access-item-x) and It seems (as im using SQL Server 2008R2) the only options are to use either a function with loops or recursive CTE's or attempt a very messy attempt using `SUBSTRING()` with `charIndex()`.

Im aware that If I had access to SQL Server 2016 I could use `string_split` but unfortunately I cant upgrade.

I do have access to SSIS but im very new to it so decided to attempt the bulk of the work within a SQL statement

Comment: Don't use that code. It's not good on performance. These two blogs will server you far better. [Jeff Moden Splitter](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/Tally+Table/72993/) and [Aaron Bertrand spit strings the right way](https://sqlperformance.com/2012/07/t-sql-queries/split-strings)

Comment: Why do you want to do this in TSQL instead of C# or Java or something similar?  It's more appropriate and easier to do there.

Comment: What is the issue with charIndex() outside of code length? It seems like the most reasonable option.

Comment: @scsimon Thanks for the links, im going to have a read through them now.

Comment: @user2023861I have access to SSIS but wont be able to make use of .NET unfortunately, I just need to manipulate the string so that I can parse out the variables I need to use elsewhere. I updated the question to include SSIS as tags

Comment: @Fritz Im concerned that Substring() along with CharIndex() can quickly turn into very unreadable code. If its my only option then i guess ill have to explore that route but for now im open to suggestions

Comment: @MasterYoda I agree it’ll be harder to read and I’m not sure which would be better performance in your environment if the charindex does work better I’d just comment the code throughly

Comment: What is the role of SSIS here? Are you using it to insert these strings in the first place? If so it should be trivial to do the splitting there.

Comment: @MasterYoda, all the strings only have 4 parts?  if that's true, you may use substring() + PARSENAME()  , it would be easier

Comment: @MartinSmith Currently im using SSIS to open a connection to the DB and retrieve a filename for each row. From there I want to manipulate the filename to parse the string into multiple columns in my select statement for each row

Comment: @EricZ Technically yes, but I also have to trim off the filepath at the beginning and the extension at the end

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I know you mentioned wanting to avoid the `charindex()` option if at all possible, but I worked it out in a hopefully semi-readable way. I find it somewhat easy to read complex functions like this when I space each parameter on a different line and use indent levels. It's not the most proper looking, but it helps with legibility:

```
with string as (select 'C:\My Documents\PDF\Walker~Thomas~19991226~20180416150322.pdf' as filepath)

select 
    substring(
        filepath,
        len(filepath)-charindex('\',reverse(filepath))+2,           --start location, after last '\'
        len(filepath)-                                              --length of path
            (len(filepath)-charindex('\',reverse(filepath))+2)-         --less characters up to last '\'
            (len(filepath)-charindex('.',filepath))                     --less file extention
        )
from string
```

Comment: Thanks Fritz, part way there. That gives me the delimited string without the filepath and extension. Now i just need to parse the delimited string

Comment: Oh, whoops. I totally forgot the splitting by tilde part. Is there a consistent number of tilde characters in each possible piece of data or does it vary?

Comment: There will always be four parts: surname, forename, birthdate, document creation date

Comment: Thanks Fritz, Im going to go with your answer as it was a great start followed up by EricZ's continuation. Nice job. I appreciate all of the help given by all of you and will be taking Simons advice on the performance side of things

Answer (score 3):

Here is a way without a splitter that shouldn't be too complicated...

```
declare @var table (filepath varchar(256))
insert into @var values
('C:\My Documents\PDF\Walker~Thomas~19991226~20180416150322.pdf')


;with string as(
select 
    x = right(filepath,charindex('\',reverse(filepath))-1) 
    from @var
)

select
    SurName= substring(x,1,charindex('~',x) - 1)
    ,FirstName = substring(x,charindex('~',x) + 1,charindex('~',x) - 1)
from string
```

Comment: reverse tends to be expensive, but the string isn't terribly long so that's good.

Comment: @scsimon thanks for the example, out of the three answers im just wondering which would be least expensive on a larger dataset

Comment: @MasterYoda the only way to tell would be to run them each, and record the times, on the *same* data set in your environment. We could do the same, but we'd need a realistic data set. Additionally, splitting the string still may be the best route via the links i set. If you choose to bench mark this, be sure to [clear the query plan cache](https://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/glenn/eight-different-ways-to-clear-the-sql-server-plan-cache/) so that you are using a fresh plan each time, versus a cached version which would speed up successive runs.

Comment: Additionally, keep in mind that if it's an argument between milliseconds, or even a few seconds, the difference could be in the `CTE` most of us used, which could be sped up by using a TEMP TABLE perhaps, or a derived table. Just be sure to check the query plan and if you have questions on that, and *why* one is faster than another, I'd post that on dba.stackexchange.com and be sure to add your query plan via https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/

Comment: @scsimon Thats 100% true, I guess ill have to test each one individually on a bigger dataset tomorrow. Thank you for your time and advice its very much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Fritz already have a great start, my answer just add on top it

```
with string as (select 'C:\My Documents\PDF\Walker~Thomas~19991226~20180416150322.pdf' as filepath)
, newstr as (
select 
    REPLACE(substring(
        filepath,
        len(filepath)-charindex('\',reverse(filepath))+2,           --start location, after last '\'
        len(filepath)-                                              --length of path
            (len(filepath)-charindex('\',reverse(filepath))+2)-         --less characters up to last '\'
            (len(filepath)-charindex('.',filepath))                     --less file extention
        ) , '~', '.') as new_part
from string
)
SELECT
      PARSENAME(new_part,4) as Surname,
      PARSENAME(new_part,3) as [First Name],
      PARSENAME(new_part,2) as [Birth Date], 
      PARSENAME(new_part,1) as [Document Created Datetime]
FROM newstr
```